# Spring Web Application Login with Active Directory

Tags: spring, active-directory, ldap, sha, spring-ldap

I had configured active directory login with spring and able to do login and fetch attributes but the problem is I have to submit raw password from my browser to server as AD requires it.

I just checked that when I posted from browser as SHA2 encoded password and passed it to AD login it gives me authentication failure. Due to security reason I need to encode password as SHA2 before posting it to Server. Is there any way to work around?

```
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
                        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("userPrincipalName", authentication.getName()));
boolean authenticateUser = ldapTemplate.authenticate("", filter.toString(),password);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-ldap/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html) doesn't say anything about accepting an encrypted password.

The password may already be encrypted when transmitted, though I don't know off hand how that works. If you want to make extra sure, you can connect via LDAPS (LDAP with SSL). [This page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/configuration.html) (under 8.1.1) makes it look as easy as replacing "ldap://" with "ldaps://" and adding the port on the end of the server name:

```
ldaps://myserver.example.com:636
```

Port 636 is the default port for LDAPS.

Comment: Spring LDAP seems to offer 'simple' authentication choice for the LDAP  Bind operation (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4511#section-4.2) but does not offer 'sasl' which would be needed if the password was already "encrytped" before being sent to the Directory Server for authentication.

To have some mean of confidentiality you need to use transport layer security all the way down;  client -> app -> Directory Server